# Autosave don’t work in 2.8

Tags: saving

About three months ago, auto save in Blender 2.8 stopped working
Since then, I downloaded 10 new builds and nothing has changed.
Blender 2.79 makes autosave fine, but 2.8 doesn’t

I checked on other computers, everything works, but on mine it doesn't, and I do not know how to fix it.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 9):

In **Preferences** > **Save and Load** > **Auto Save**,  do you have the **Auto Save** **Temporary Files** option checked ?
[image]

Next check in **Preferences** > **File Paths** > **Data** > **Temporary Files**, left click the **folder icon** to see if you have any .blender files saved at this location.
[image]

This is what i have in my Temp folder:
[image]

Note that holding down the **Alt** key and **left clicking** that little folder icon will take you directly to the location on your hard drive from where you can drag one of the saved  .bland files onto your desktop and then open it again in Blender.
[image]

Comment: Also check the system console. If using an addon (maybe new in the last three months,  that runs a modal timer, will see a "_cannot  autosave while modal is running_" or siimilar message displayed.

Comment: It looks like in my case it is "autoload textures" addon

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this as an answer since this was added as a [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134722/autosave-don-t-work-in-2-8#comment254661_134741) and it solved my problem.

If a modal operator is running, the autosave feature won't work.

Make sure to disable all add-ons and selectively re-enable them until the autosave feature stops working to know which one is the culprit.

I didn't get a warning about it in the console though, so it's a bit troublesome if you use a large number of addons which could potentially be full-time running a modal operator in the background.

Comment: What is a modal operator?

Comment: @aggregate1166877 it's an operator that keeps running in the background until it finishes running. see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#modal-execution