# Autosave has stopped working

Tags: saving

Autosave no longer saving files.

version 2.91, no addons besides factory checked ones

Comment: Please add some more details, like what OS are you using? Did you run a serach for `*.blend` at your disk?

Comment: OSX Catalina 10.15.7 

I have searched and found no autosaves since yesterday. A clean install fixes it, then it randomly stops autosaving.

Comment: Sorry, I can help with OSX. In Linux I would suggest to look to `/tmp/`. You may also try running the portable version, maybe it helps. But those are just blind guesses, I never used OSX.

Comment: @user85015 This may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134722/autosave-don-t-work-in-2-8/221362